# textbox onchange not triggered

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Using a Javascript library - Calendar_Impl.js for a calendar control. There is an image beside the textbox, clicking on which, a calendar is shown. Selecting the date in that calendar will fill the date in that textbox.

```
<asp:textbox onchange="chkDate();"></asp:textbox>
<img onclick="javascript: showCalendar();"/>
```

I would like to perform a check on that date, once user selects a date. But the onchange or onblur do not work at all. When text is entered manually then the chkDate() works. Filling the date by clicking the image, doesnt work.

Without disturbing the calendar.js, can i do something to fire the event.

Comment: What library are you using? Any decent calendar control will expose an event to capture changes.

Comment: I guess the `onchange` won't fire *until textbox loses focus or you hit enter.*

Comment: its Calendar_Impl.js. I can see those functions but dont know how to use them.

Comment: Can you make a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of code?

Comment: I can't find find any documentation on a library named "Calendar_Impl.js". Please post a link to the API, or at least the source code.

Answer (score 1):

That's true the HTML listeners `onchange` and `blur` only works when you focussed the input field. I'm not 100% sure, but i think you can invoke the function using a javascript listener. Try something like this:

Add a ID to your textbox:

```
<asp:textbox id="chkDateTextbox" onchange="chkDate();"></asp:textbox>
```

Add javascript onchange listener:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload= function () {
        if(window.addEventListener) 
        {
            document.getElementById('chkDateTextbox').addEventListener('change', chkDate, false);
        } 
        else if (window.attachEvent)
        {
            document.getElementById('chkDateTextbox').attachEvent("onchange", chkDate);
        }
    }
</script>
```